# Is there a simple way to set epochs when using TFRecords with Tensorflow Estimators

Tags: tensorflow, tfrecord

There is a nice way to set epochs when feeding numpy arrays into an estimator

```
  tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
     x,
     y=None,
     batch_size=128,
     num_epochs=1 ,
     shuffle=None,
     queue_capacity=1000,
     num_threads=1  
   )
```

But I can't track down a similar method with TFRecords, most people seem to just stick it in a loop

```
 i = 0 
 while ( i < 100000):
   model.train(input_fn=input_fn, steps=100)
```

Is there a clean way to explicitly set the number of epochs for TFRecords with estimators ?

Comment: are you using dataset api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set number of epoch with `dataset.repeat(num_epochs)`. Dataset pipeline outputs a dataset object, a tuple (features, labels) of batch size, that is inputed to `model.train()`

```
dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(file.tfrecords)
dataset = tf.shuffle().repeat()
...
dataset = dataset.batch()
```

In order to make it work, you set `model.train(steps=None, max_steps=None)` In this case, you let Dataset API to handle epochs count by generating `tf.errors.OutOfRange` error or `StopIteration` exception once num_epoch is reached.